# Can I remove all ".0000" appearances on my webshop?

Tags: javascript, numbers, hide

I am working on an e-commerce website where 500 products + specs are automatically imported from a CSV-file.

Unfortunately some of the specs have ".0000' in addition to the main number.
For example:

Product 1:

- Depth: 40.0000
- Height: 78.0000
- Width: 125.0000

Product 2:

- Depth: 20.0000
- Height: 42.0000
- Wight: 200.0000

I want the numbers to be 'round' (40 / 78 / 125 / 20 / 42 / 200)

I am a rookie with CSS/JS, but I am able to find the part where I can add custom CSS :)

Would it be possible to hide all ".0000" with code?

Comment: Try and figure out how these numbers are being put on the page. Then you may be able to edit them as they’re displayed

Comment: Thanks, but I don't really understand what you mean with "how they're being put on the page"? 
The webshop imports the data from a CSV-file...

Comment: So you're not in control of the display of those numbers? Can you modify the CSV file?

Comment: I could, but the file auto-syncs everyday (to keep track on stocklevels). So if I change it today, it'll be back tomorrow.

Comment: AFAIK This isn't something that CSS can do. Not without significantly more information about how it's displayed on the webshop.

Comment: Okay, thanks anyway for your help !

Comment: I don't think you will receive a quality answer with that question. So please visit [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), take [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see what and [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Comment: As others mentioned, fix it by fixing your import data. If you fix how the csv gets updated, you don't have to change anything on your frontend, which seems to be the easiest way forward

Answer (score 0):

use parseInt built-in function to round the number to absolute one or use parseFloat to round the number:

```js
const number = parseInt(40.0000);
alert(number)
```

Comment: Thanks Ehsan. This applies to 500 different product pages, with varying values. For example: 

Product A: 

Diepte: 40.0000
Hoogte: 78.0000
Breedte: 125.0000

Product B:
Diepte: 20.0000
Hoogte: 42.0000
Breedte: 200.0000

Would your code work for all these numbers?

Comment: That function is converting each number to absolute one. no matter how many products you have. as far as they are only numbers this function could be applied

Comment: Okay, that sounds great! 
And it's just a matter of copy/paste your code at the CSS of the page? No further code needed?

Comment: Try it. if there was a problem just ask :)

Comment: OK, so I tried and copied the code in the custom CSS part of the theme. However, I don't see any effect. Still numbers with .0000 ?

Comment: you need to paste the code in js part of your code. it is not a CSS code

Comment: Ah ;) .. tried again in JS. But still no changes.

Comment: can you share the whole code or a sample so i can create the bug

Comment: sorry, wouldn't know how to?

Answer (score 0):

You can use parseint method..parseInt(value)

Comment: Thanks. Could you provide a bit more detailed information / code? 
I wouldn't know how to implement this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, this is not the best aprouch, becouse it will test evry element on your website and it will search for strings that contains **.0000** and it will replace it with **empty string**

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
[...document.querySelectorAll("*")]//query selector for all the elements in DOM
.filter(e => e.childNodes && [...e.childNodes].find(n => n.nodeValue?.match(".0000")))//filter all the elements that contains .0000
.forEach(element => element.innerText = (element.innerText.replace(/.0000/, "")));//replace it with empty string
});
```

```html
<ul>
<li>Diepte: 40.0000</li>
<li>Hoogte: 78.0000</li>
<li>Breedte: 125.0000</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks, when I run your code it works perfectly, however if I copy the code to my page, nothing happens. (Tried to paste in CSS and JS-section as well)

Comment: I have change it to run on DOMContentLoaded

Comment: Tried again, still see no changes